# Dash Data Table Horizontal Scroll Bar Default to Right

Tags: python, datatable, plotly-dash, horizontal-scrolling

I have a Data Table in Dash (python) that works very well.  I would like the scroll bar to default to the right - that is, to show the most right information in the data table.  The current default is the scroll bar is set to the left.  I am using time series data for a finance table, so I want to show the most current year, which is all the way to the right (don't want to make it left) and have the scroll bar set so that its show the right and then you would need to scroll to the left to see the left.

Here is what I have and it works fine except for the issue above:

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = dash_table.DataTable(
    id='table',
    columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns],
    data=df.to_dict('records'),
    fixed_columns={'headers': True, 'data': 1},
    fixed_rows={'headers': True, 'data': 1},
    # style_cell={'textAlign': 'left'},
    style_cell={'fontFamily': 'sans-serif', 'fontSize': '12px', 'border': '0px'}, #, 'boxShadow': '10 0'},
    style_table={'minWidth': '60%'},
    style_cell_conditional=[
        {
            'if': {'column_id': i},
            'textAlign': 'left',
            'fontWeight': 'bold'
        } for i in ['$ in millions']#, 'C']

    ],
    style_header={
        'backgroundColor': 'white',
        'fontWeight': 'bold',
        'borderBottom': '1px solid black'
    },
    # style_as_list_view=True,
)
# $ in millions
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

Comment: Did you get anywhere on this? I have exactly the same problem

Answer (score 0):

If you were making your Dash application using JavaScript, the solution would have been pretty straight forward, unfortunately there is no straight forward answer other than creating 'assets' folder and creating a HTML file with a function to scroll right. The easiest way to tackle this, in my opinion, is to just re-arranging the columns backward by doing `df = df.columns[::-1]` or by slicing and rearranging the df.